# How to ask an immutable question?

Tags: discussion

Is there a concise but polite way to say that my question `Y` is immutable, to avoid it being addressed as if it were an unasked question `X`?

If possible, please assume I lead this question about it, with it.

Comment: I don't think that's what immutable means, but I think I get the gist... you're asking how to ask a question that won't get interpreted as an XY question?

Comment: @BoltClock - yeah, I tried to think of a good scenario here where it'd be useful, but I suppose that exact thing is what I'm hoping to avoid in certain low-level coding questions.

Comment: So, I would say if XY is what you're worried of, you can make your constraints clear in your question... 'I know Y would solve my issue, but because of Z, I can't use this'. Isn't that enough? :/. IMHO, it should be

Comment: @Patrice - It definitely is, though Z can sometimes be difficult to exhaust satisfactorily.  For example, perhaps I'm violating the type system of C++ because it "feels comfy," but want to ask about an aliasing issue that might arise from it.  My goal X is to make a program, so the question could be answered by "prefer something else" or taken to the extreme, "just use Rust" unless I provide a Z that precludes it

Comment: Pay a freelancer to answer it.

Comment: @MartinJames - y'know, that's the fairest answer this question could've had, you are absolutely right

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Can we get people to directly ask about their problems instead of topics they think might be related?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56366/194720), [Do I have to explain why I am asking a question on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97170/194720). Suffice it to say, this is not a new issue.

Comment: Also on MSE: [WHY do people ask “why” questions with the “why” capitalized and excessively formatted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for)

Comment: What is stopping you from clearly & politely saying what you mean in such a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to be extra descriptive in the question text, to explain what are the obvious solutions, and how your situation differs, making the obvious solutions untenable.

This should hopefully make the people answering to avoid repeating what you already know.

It can also backfire though. If the question becomes a "wall of text" some may skip reading it altogether.